# I met an Invalid type error when i tried to deploy on vercel

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to make a web application by using nextjs with typescript. There was no error when i develped on localhost. I met an error when i tried to deploy on vercel, and then I could check the error when i run 'npm run lint'.

Here is the error.

```
./components/post/PostList.tsx
11:42  Error: Invalid type "string | undefined" of template literal expression.  @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
```

```
// PostList.tsx
export const PostList = ({posts} : Posts) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="mx-auto grid max-w-[768px] gap-y-4 px-4 pb-[100px] md:max-w-[1080px] md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-x-6 md:gap-y-[30px]">
        {posts.map((post, i) => {
          return (
            <Link key={i} href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}> // Here is the error line
              <a>
                <PostItem post={post.frontMatter} />
              </a>
            </Link>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

slug is just a string of file name. I don't know how to go through this error..

```
// post.slug
slug: 'hello-world copy 3'
```

---

Here is the other tsx file and same error.

```
// [slug].tsx
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = (context) => {
  // get content for each blog
  const mdfile =  fs.readFileSync(`posts/${context.params?.slug}.md`); // Here is same error...
  const { data: frontMatter, content } = matter(mdfile);

  return {
    props: {
      frontMatter,
      content,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide a default value to the parameter

```
<Link key={i} href={`/blog/${post.slug || ''}`}>
```

Or, better, check for the `post.slug` to be defined:

```
{
    posts.map((post, i) => {
      if (!post.slug) return <div key={i}>Post missing</div>
      return (
        <Link key={i} href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}>
          <a>
            <PostItem post={post.frontMatter} />
          </a>
        </Link>
      );
    });
  }
```

For the `[slug].tsx` you could add a null check and return default values when the variable is not defined:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = (context) => {
  // get content for each blog
  if (!context.params || !context.params.slug) return { props: { frontMatter: 'default-value', content: 'default-value' } }
  
  const mdfile = fs.readFileSync(`posts/${context.params.slug}.md`);
  const { data: frontMatter, content } = matter(mdfile);

  return {
    props: {
      frontMatter,
      content,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: But i found same error on other tsx file.
`const mdfile = fs.readFileSync(`posts/${context.params?.slug}.md`);`
and   ` || '' `is not worked ..